# What are your homebrew club dues?

Tags: club

I moved to a new area without an existing homebrew club.  We've been around for about 18 months now and I'd like to start doing some official stuff.

[The Sudzers](http://sudzers.org/), my previous club charged $20 a year to be an official member.  I'm not entirely sure what they paid for.

Do you pay club dues?  What do they go to?

Comment: I've never joined a club. Probably should one of these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ann Arbor Brewers Guild is $15 per person per year, or $20 per couple per year.  Benefits are access to the club mailing list, access to club events, ability to participate in group ingredient buys, and ability to rent club equipment.

Comment: How does renting club equipment work?

Answer (score 1):

$20 in January. $30 the rest of the year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of The Impaling Alers in Kent, WA (Seattle). Dues are due each January, and prorated if you join mid-year. I think it's $15 or $20/year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of Minnesota Home brewers and our dues are $15 per year.

Answer (score 1):

$30 for the year for [Hop Barley and the Alers](http://hopbarley.org).  The dues primarily cover rent, but they also go to reimburse for club brews, food brought to the meeting (we serve dinner), as well as cover expenses for a couple of officers attending the NHC.  The membership fees don't entirely cover the costs however... a large portion of our money is made from a yearly auction and we make a minimal amount from our yearly competition, Reggale and Dredhop.  In the past we also printed and mailed our newsletters, but we stopped that and now just put it on the website.

Answer (score 1):

$15.  We have a fair number of club parties and events throughout the year so that's where most of it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The [Green Bay Rackers](http://www.rackers.org/) charge 25 dollars a year for fees, although I think most of that goes towards club functions and possibly the web site.